# Error when rendering a partial (RoR) passing the form as a local variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my main template I have the following:

```
 <%= render :partial => "delivery_date", :collection => @brand.delivery_dates, :locals => {:form => f} %>
```

However when the partial tries to use the form local variable, I get this error

```
Showing app/views/brands/_delivery_date.html.erb where line #2 raised:

wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
Extracted source (around line #2):

1: <%= delivery_date.id %>
2: <%= form.text_field :name %>
3: <% new_or_existing = delivery_date.new_record? ? 'new' : 'existing' %>
4: <% prefix = "brand[#{new_or_existing}_delivery_date_attributes][]" %>
5: <% fields_for prefix, delivery_date do |dd_f| %>
```

Does anyone understand what this error means?

Actually I want to do

```
<% form.fields_for delivery_date do |dd_f| %>
```

but that fails as well.

I tried replacing `:locals` with `:locals => { :f => f }` and referring to the form using `f` in the partial. No effect, the error then is `undefined method or variable f`.

...

Ok rather than asking you to debug an error, the question is also how to render fields_for in a nested partial form:

In main template:

```
<% form_for @object do |f| %>
    <% render :partial => 'child', :collection: @object.child %>
<% end %>
```

In child template:

```
<% form.fields_for child do |c_f| %>
    <%= c_f.text_field :foo %>
<% end %>
```

What is the appropriate way to pass this form object?

Sorry forgot to add environment:

Ruby 1.8.7

Rails 2.3.? (have to look up minor version, don't have the code in front of me)

(I know this is a newbie question :(   )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's weird. It should work as you have it with :form or :f. If you're using Ruby 1.9, maybe there's some difference in how local variables work. I would try `:locals => { "f" => f }` with a string key instead of symbol and see if that helps. Also, does it work to use a simpler case like `:locals => { :x => 2 }`?

Comment: :locals => { :x => 2 } works.

Coencidentally I realized since I was also rendering this template in a link_to_function, it might have been that I was not looking at the error stack completely and missing where the error was comming from. I think this helped :P I will keep at it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you are passing :form => f along with the partial, therefore you should refer to "f" and not "form"

just replace all instances of "form" with "f" in your partial otherwise ruby/rails will think that you are trying to call the form builder method (and that requires at least one argument, hence the error message)

Comment: You also need to change the `:locals` hash to `{:f => f}` in that case.

Comment: Thanks! Um how does the locals hash works? :form => f that does not set the form variable? Sorry a bit confused on that.

Comment: This does not work. If I use `:locals => { :f => f }` and use `f` instead of `form` in the partial, i get undefined variable error.